# just wanted to know what am i doing wrong in the end of this script that doesnt put my checkdate in to cal command

Tags: shell, scripting

```bsh
#Purpose: Validate a date
#Usage: chkdate year month day
#
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 0
fi
year=$1; month=$2; day=$3; extra=$4
if [[ "$extra" != "" ]]; then
        # Too much data!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 1
fi
if [[ "$year" == "" || "$month" == "" || "$day" == "" ]]; then
        # Not enough data!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 2
fi
if [[ ! ( $year =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $month =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $day =~ ^[0-9]+$ ) ]]; then
        # Date not numeric!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 3
fi
#Remove leading zeros if any
year=$(echo "$year" | bc)
month=$(echo "$month" | bc)
day=$(echo "$day" | bc)
if [[ $year -lt 1 || $year -gt 9999 || $month -lt 1 || $month -gt 12 || $day -lt 1 || $day -gt 31 ]]; then
        # Date out of range!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 4
fi
if [[ ( $month == 1 || $month == 3 || $month == 5 || $month == 7 || $month == 8 || $month == 10 || $month == 12 ) && $day -gt 31 ]]; then
        # Invalid day!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 5
fi
if [[ ( $month == 4 || $month == 6 || $month == 9 || $month == 11 ) && $day -gt 30 ]]; then
        # Invalid day!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 6
fi
if [[ $month == 2 && $(($year%100)) == 0 ]]; then
        if [[ $(($year%400)) == 0 ]]; then
                isLeapYear=1
        else
                isNotLeapYear=1
        fi
elif [[ $month == 2 && $(($year%4)) == 0 ]]; then
        isLeapYear=1
else
        isNotLeapYear=1
fi
if [[ $month == 2 && $day -gt 28 && $isNotLeapYear ]]; then
        # Not Leap year!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 7
fi
if [[ $month == 2 && $day -gt 29 && $isLeapYear ]]; then
        # Invalid day!
        echo Usage: chkdate year month day
        exit 8
fi
while [[ $# -ne [1-8] ]]; do
cal << ( $year $month $day )
fi
echo $year $month $day is valid date
```

Comment: See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216) and look at the paragraphs on "here documents" and "here strings".

Comment: Also, please do some debugging on your own before you ask for help. If you know that you have a problem at the end of your script, you should post just the part that has the problem. And ***explain*** what is going wrong.

Comment: The end of a `while ...; do` should be marked with `done`, not `fi`. And the loop will run infinitely, because the body never changes `$#`.

Comment: What is the `while` loop for, anyway? You already checked the arguments at the top of the script, why are you checking the number of arguments.

Comment: The `cal` command takes a year and month, not a day. It shows a calendar for the whole month. What are you expecting your script to show from that line?

Comment: @Barmar, my cal does: `cal --version` outputs `cal from util-linux 2.24.2`, and `cal --help` shows usage `cal [options] [[[day] month] year]`. Giving a specific day shows that month with the day highlighted.

Comment: I must have an older `cal`, it doesn't even have `--version`.

Comment: im trying to use cal commands to validate dates and i get the error and whe i try fixing it this is what i get

Comment: while [[ $# -ne [1-8] ]]; do
cal <<< ( $year $month $day )
done
echo $year $month $day is valid date
"check" 71L, 1821C written                                    
hgolmohammadi1@matrix:~/Lab2> check 1989 06 17
./check: line 69: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./check: line 69: `cal <<< ( $year $month $day )'

Answer (score 2):

- Add shebang, since you are using `[[` most probably `#!/bin/bash` is what you want
- Try to stick with one test syntax (either single bracket `[` or double `[[`)
- Instead of `<<` (here document) most probably you want `<<<` (here string)
- At the end of the script `while` loop is not closed, expect `done` somewhere
- There is one too many `fi`. (instead of `done`???)
- It is good idea to quit from loop somehow...

Comment: Actually, he probably doesn't want a here string, either. `cal` takes its parameters as arguments, not stdin.

Comment: That's true, but with here string `cal` at least outputs something, although not what one could expect.

Comment: im trying to use cal commands to validate dates and i get the error

Comment: while [[ $# -ne [1-8] ]]; do
cal <<< ( $year $month $day )
done
echo $year $month $day is valid date
"check" 71L, 1821C written                                    
hgolmohammadi1@matrix:~/Lab2> check 1989 06 17
./check: line 69: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./check: line 69: `cal <<< ( $year $month $day )'

Comment: k i checked everything and the only problem i get is when i run this  check 1989 06 16 it gives me ./check: line 68: [: [1-8]: integer expression expected

Comment: k i changed my script to this do u know why it is not running cal command still?

Comment: i cant send script here for some reason it says its too long

Comment: hey is there a possibilty that u can delete this answer becuase i dont want other people from my course see my script even though it is wrong

Comment: if [$# == $year $month $day  ] ; then cal $day $month $year  i want to know whats the problem here with this