# bash script that reads user input and uses "cal" command to validate dates

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, cal

I want to write a script that reads my input (for example if my script is called "check", then I would type "check 9 4 1993" and that input would go through the cal command and will check through the calendar whether it is a valid date or not).

My idea below is that if the input that goes through the cal command gives an error it will mean that it's not a valid date, and vice-versa if there's no error than the date is valid. I do realize there's something terribly wrong with this draft (I can't figure out how to make it so that my input will go through the cal command), but I will appreciate some suggestions. Here's the draft anyways:

```
#!/bin/bash

day=$1; month=$2; year=$3
day=$(echo "$day" | bc)
month=$(echo "$month" | bc)
year=$(echo "$year" | bc)

cal $day $ month $year 2> /dev/null
if [[$? -eq 0 ]]; then
   echo "This is a valid date"
else
   echo "This is an invalid date"
fi
```

Comment: similar question, not dup: [just wanted to know what am i doing wrong in the end of this script that doesnt put my checkdate in to cal command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159888/4667)

Comment: What is the purpose behind `day=$(echo "$day" | bc)`?  Input validation? Removal of leading zeros?.  In either case you could also do `day=$((10#$day))` which uses the shell's own arithmetic expansion instead of forking a `bc` process.

Comment: Almost exactly the same problem as in [bash question about if and then](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159941/80216); and very similar to [how to write this if command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159930/80216)

Answer (score 4):

In some Linux distros that I have checked (e,g, Ubuntu 14.04), the packaged `cal` comes from BSD and not GNU Coreutils.  The BSD version does not seem to accept days as a parameter; only months and years.  The Ubuntu version does have a -H YYYY-MM-DD option, but that doesn't seem to help.

Instead I would use the `date` utility.  Assuming the GNU Coreutils under Linux I think I would rewrite your script something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

day=$((10#$1))
month=$((10#$2))
year=$((10#$3))

if date -d $year-$month-$day > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # cal $month $year
    echo "This is a valid date"
else
    echo "This is an invalid date"
fi
```

Notes:

- I am using the shell's own [arithmetic expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) to validate input/remove leading zeros, instead of forking a new `bc` process for each parameter
- I am using [GNU date](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html#date-invocation) to parse the input date
- The date command may be used directly as the `if` conditional expression.  `if` works by checking process exit codes.  Commonly the `[` or `[[` executables are used instead, but there is no reason other programs can be used if they exit with useful exit codes
- I'm not sure if you actually wanted the `cal` output for correct dates or not.  If you do, simply uncomment the `cal` line.

Answer (score 2):

There is a space between your dollar `$` and your `month` variable:

```
cal $day $ month $year 2> /dev/null
```

It should be:

```
cal $day $month $year 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Damn, what a rookie mistake by me, thanks for noticing :)

The script works as intended now, i have the right output.

Answer (score 2):

`[[` is actually a command, and like other commands you need whitespace to separate its arguments:

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
# ...^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type the date formatted as "%Y-%m-%d" or "%m/%d/&Y" (e.g. 2020-11-29 or 11/29/2020), you can check the date validity using gnu date (gdate) like this:

```
gdate -d "$1" +'%Y-%m-%d' > /dev/null 2>&1  # don't display any output
status=$(echo $?)                           # get error code
if [[ $status = 1 ]]                        # if date is invalid
then
  { echo "This date doesn't exist. Enter valid date!"; exit 1; }
else
  ...
```

Hope I got the question right and that this helps somebody. Sure worked for me :)